# How to extract a string between two points and a dot

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have the following string in R:

```
11:22334455.CEL
```

I would like to extract only the number series after : and before ., that means

```
22334455
```

I was trying with `gsub("\\:*", "", 11:22334455.CEL)`, but I got the following result:

```
11216803.CEL
```

How could I fix the `gsub` function to get only `22334455`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex capture group (the parentheses `(\\d+)`) to capture what you want.

```
sub(".*:(\\d+)\\..*", "\\1", "11:22334455.CEL")

[1] "22334455"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove characters before `':'` and after `'.'`

```r
gsub(".*:|\\..*", "", "11:22334455.CEL")

# [1] "22334455"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stringr`s `str_extract` with `group`.

`\\d+` detects one or more digits, here between `:` and `\\.` (escaped period) within braces that define the capture group.

```
library(stringr)

str_extract("11:22334455.CEL", ":(\\d+)\\.", group = 1)
[1] "22334455"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws("11:22334455.CEL", whitespace = ".*:|\\..*")
[1] "22334455"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_extract` with look-behind `(?<=:)` to assert that the match only starts **after** the colon, and look-ahead `(?=\\.)` to assert that the match must be followed by a `.`:

```
str_extract("11:22334455.CEL", "(?<=:)\\d+(?=\\.)")
[1] "22334455"
```